# Accessing: name="recipe[''name'] inJavascriptMVC

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, javascriptmvc

I run through this Making a Cookbook tutorial (http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=getstarted)

Since I work with rails i changed the input names from *name* and *description* to **recipe['name']** and **recipe['description']**

Saving the record via rails work fine, but as soon as JMVC updates the view **it renders [object Object]** instead of the title/description

Controller:

```
'form submit': function( el, ev ){
    ev.preventDefault();
    new Cookbook.Models.Recipe(el.formParams()).save();
},
'recipe.created subscribe': function( called, recipe ){
    $("#recipe tbody").append( this.view("list", {recipes:[recipe]}) );
    $("#recipe form input[type!=submit]").val(""); //clear old vals
},
```

Form:

```
<form>
        <div class="field">
        <label for="recipe_name">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" size="30" name="recipe[name]" id="recipe_name">
      </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label for="recipe_description">Description</label><br>
            <input type="text" size="30" name="recipe[description]" id="recipe_description">
          </div>
    <input type='submit' value='Create'/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask questions on JavaScriptMVC's forum.  I don't check Stackoverflow that often.

The problem is you should be passing to Recipe(el.formParams().recipe).  Model expects attributes.